# Issue with yum repository in centos

Tags: centos, centos7, yum

I get the following error when I execute the command yum repolist;

```
[root@xyz yum.repos.d]# yum repolist

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks

base                                                                                                                           | 2.8 kB  00:00:00     
http:// mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for base: Damaged repomd.xml file
Trying other mirror.
base/7/x86_64                                                                                                                  | 2.8 kB  00:00:00     

http:// mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for base: Damaged repomd.xml file
Trying other mirror.
extras/7/x86_64                                                                                                                | 2.8 kB  00:00:00     

http:// mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for extras: Damaged repomd.xml file
Trying other mirror.
updates/7/x86_64                                                                                                               | 2.8 kB  00:00:00     

http:// mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for updates: Damaged repomd.xml file
Trying other mirror.

repo id                                                                repo name                                                                status
base/7/x86_64                                                          CentOS-7 - Base                                                          0
extras/7/x86_64                                                        CentOS-7 - Extras                                                        0
updates/7/x86_64                                                       CentOS-7 - Updates                                                       0
repolist: 0
```

Comment: Have you tried `yum clean all` - if not please try that and see if the error changes or goes.

Answer (score 0):

Yum was not configured and got resolved once configured.